# algorithm for determining if a set of (x,y) coordinates fall inside a square?

Tags: geometry

I don't need a working example, just a pointing in the right direction.

I was wondering if an algorithm or formula exists that can determine if an (x,y) point falls inside a square positioned at a certain point with certain dimensions.

I'm not sure if that is clear or not. But any tips would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Just check whether the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are within the bounds of the rectangle (square in this case).

Comment: How is the square specified? Is it axis-aligned?

Comment: Is your square aligned to the axes or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point lies inside a square of side length r, located at (h,k) if the following inequality is satisfied:

$\left|(x - h) + (y - k)  \right|+\left| (x - h)  - (y - k)  \right| \le r$

(Assuming the square is aligned with the x and y axis.)

Comment: What does located at (h,k) mean? is that the center of the square? or some other point?

Comment: It's the center of the square.

Comment: From a performance point of view, this isn't really the best way to check whether or not the point is inside the square.

Answer (score 1):

Let say $L(1)$ and $L(2)$ are two parallel sides of the square. By comparing perpendicular distances from the origin of these two lines, we can always tell which one is nearer to the origin. Hence, wlog, we let $L(1)$ be the nearer line.

Note:- If the origin lies between L(1) and L(2), relocate the origin to the left by a certain amount may be necessary.

Let the point to be tested be $P(x, y)$. The possible locations of $P$ are $A$, $B$, or $C$.

[image]

The knowledge of testing whether a point is on the origin side or not is assumed. If not, check an $LP$ problem.

Let $P$ goes through the origin side tests wrt $L(1)$ and $L(2)$ respectively.

1. If both tests show that $P$ is on the origin side of both lines, $\implies P$ is at $A \implies P$ is outside.
2. If $P$ is on the origin side of $L(1)$ but on the non-origin side of $L(2)$, $\implies$ no such point.
3. If $P$ is on the non-origin side of $L(1)$, $P$ could be at $B$ or $C$.

   If $P$ is on the origin side of $L(2)$, $P$ could be $A$ or $B$.

   Intermediate conclusion $\implies P$ is at $B$
4. If both tests show that $P$ is on the non-origin side of both lines, $\implies P$ is at $C \implies P$ is outside.

The process is repeated for the other pair of straight lines.

Note. The are other (simpler) cases that one (or even both) of the sides lie(s) on the axes.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I have redesignated your point $(x\mid y)$ as $(p\mid q)$, because I used the letters $x$ and $y$ in the preparation of this answer.

I have designated the vertices of your square as follows: $(m\mid n)$, $(m+A\mid n+B)$, $(m+A-B\mid n+A+B)$ and $(m-B\mid n+A)$. $m$, $n$, $A$ and $B$ can have any real values, and the resulting square is not necessarily aligned with the axes. $(p\mid q)$, as I said, is the point to be tested. Caveat: $A^2+B^2\gt 0$.

If,  and only if, both (1) and (2) [below] are true,
1. $Am+Bn+A^2+B^2-Ap-Bq$ is of the same sign as $Ap+Bq-Am-Bn$.
2. $An-Bm+A^2+B^2-Aq+Bp$ is of the same sign as $Aq-Bp-An+Bm$.
then $(p\mid q)$ is within the square. Caveat: For the purpose of evaluating the signs of the four expressions in (1) or (2), a value of $0$ is considered equivalent to $+$ or $-$.

Comment: That was very helpful! Thank you.